# Am I using Lambda RequestResponse correctly? Or is there a better alternative - Synchronous Lambda Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Hi there I am stuck / or unsure on my lambda function. I am making a telegram bot to convert videos to GIFs. My current set up is to host the polling bot on an EC2 instance, and when the user sends the bot a video, it triggers a RequestResponse lambda function that then processes the GIF and sends it back to the user as a s3 object with a download link. The GIF conversions should only take a few seconds -- is there anything wrong with using synchronous here? Can you advise if there is anything else I could do?